# Message queues and database inserts

Tags: postgresql, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I'm new to message queues and am intrigued by their capabilities and use. I have an idea about how to use it but wonder if it is the best use of this tool. I have an application that picks up and reads spreadsheets, transforms the data business objects for database storage. My application needs to read and be able to update several hundred thousand records, but I'm running into performance issues holding onto these objects and bulk inserting into the database.

Would having have two different applications (one to read the spreadsheets, one to store the records) using a message queue be proper utilization of a message queue? Obviously there are some optimizations I need to make in my code and is going to be my first step, but wanted to hear thoughts from those that have used message queues.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be an improper use of the queue, but its hard to tell if in you scenario adding a message queue will having any affect on the performance problems you mentioned. We would need more information.

Are you adding one message to a queue to tell a process to convert a spreadsheet and a second message when the data is ready for loading? or are you thinking of adding on message per data record? (That might get expensive fast, and probably won't increase the performance).